# Php download file from link that downloads file

Tags: php, file, curl

I'm trying to use php to download files that are created and downloaded when you call to a url.

In this case i'm trying to programmatically download a txt file from the dutch weather institute wich can be done by going to(in this example) this url http://projects.knmi.nl/klimatologie/daggegevens/getdata_dag.cgi?lang=nl&byear=2016&bmonth=6&bday=20&eyear=2016&emonth=6&eday=22&variabele=FHX&variabele=FXX&variabele=TG&variabele=TN&variabele=TX&stations=249&submit=Download+data+set

Going to that url downloads the file.

I want to do this with php so I can use the contents of the file to make custom charts.

Does anyone know how to do this with php?

Comment: You should tell us what you tried so far, what the problem is you actually face with that attempt. How else do you expect us to help with your code?

Comment: Okay I was wrong, file_get_contents does work. I think I had a fault in the link and thats why my content was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using file_get_contents(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

or using CURL functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

EDIT:  CURL Solution:

```
$url = 'http://projects.knmi.nl/klimatologie/daggegevens/getdata_dag.cgi?lang=nl&byear=2016&bmonth=6&bday=20&eyear=2016&emonth=6&eday=22&variabele=FHX&variabele=FXX&variabele=TG&variabele=TN&variabele=TX&stations=249&submit=Download+data+set';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: File_get_contents gets the content of a file, in this case the file is downloaded from the link. I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: `file_get_contents` will fail depending on PHP configuration, ie: `allow_url_fopen`

Comment: your environment may have this function disabled for security reasons. that's why I also mentioned the CURL option... which I recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$content = file_get_contents("The URL here");
echo $content;
```

Comment: This will fail depending on PHP configuration, ie: `allow_url_fopen`

Comment: I tried it on my own server and received the content just fine.

Comment: It depends on your PHP configuration, there are a lot of hosting providers disallow this by default